# update statement value in multi table at once

Tags: sql-server

I have over 100 tables in SQL Server 2000 with the same column name in each table. Now I want to update a value in 100 tables at once using a SQL update statement.

How do I do that? I try to google and stackoverflow but not really help.

Thanks so much

Comment: This is the kind of thing that should be handled by having a single table with this column in it and some sort of static identifier so that other tables can link to it... Then you'd only need to update a single table instead of 100...

Comment: if you had single table then what would be your update statement and what paameter you will pass.meanwhile you can get idea from this link.https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171254/script-to-delete-records-in-multiple-table/174557#174557

Answer (score 0):

Create a cursor for all table in your database and using dynamic query to execute.
This script will be help you do this.

```
--USE [Your DB]
--GO
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @sqlQuery VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE curTable CURSOR FOR SELECT name FROM sys.objects WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE' AND name NOT IN ('sysdiagrams')
OPEN curTable
FETCH NEXT FROM curTable INTO @tableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @sqlQuery = 'UPDATE ' + @tableName + 'SET [YourCol1] = [YourVal1], [YourCol2] = [YourVal2] ...'
    PRINT @sqlQuery
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlQuery

    FETCH NEXT FROM curTable INTO @tableName
END
CLOSE curTable
DEALLOCATE curTable
```